# Regular expression Manipulation in Ruby using gsub

Tags: ruby, gsub

When I do `"www.example.com/test/test".gsub('/test','')`, I get `"www.example.com"`, but my desired result is `"www.example.com/test"`. That is, only the last `"/test"` should be removed. How do we achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"www.example.com/test/test".gsub(/\/test$/,'')`

UPDATE after comment

Event if it is working with `gsub`, `sub` seems more appropriate as you only want to replace one time :

`"www.example.com/test/test".sub(/\/test$/,'')`

Comment: If you only want one substitution, use `#sub` instead of `#gsub`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"www.example.com/test/test".sub('/test','')
```

Comment: @Viveikt This is not working the way you may want. This is not removing the last `/test` but the first one.